# Retrieving database elements to listview failed

Tags: android, database

> My program contains an activity and a database class.i tried to access the database elements from the acivity class through an inner class named getclicker which extends listactivity. I've given the logcat  also.pls help me to solve the problem

FirstActivity.java
package example.showevent1;

```
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v4.app.*;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;

public class FirstActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnItemSelectedListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    classdbOpenHelper eventsData;
    classdbOpenHelper eventsData1;
    Cursor cursor1;
     TextView userSelection;
     Button okButton;
     Button addButton;

     Button change_date_but;
     TextView date;
     TextView show;
     EditText edittext; 
     ListView listView;
      public static final int Date_dialog_id = 1;
      private int mYear;
      private int mMonth;
      private int mDay;

    private static final String[] items={"Yalahanka","Rajaji nagar","Sivaji Nagar","Koramangala","RT Nagar", "Banashankari","Yashwanthpura","Hebbal"};



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
         okButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
         addButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);

         change_date_but = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
         date = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);//KEY_DATE
         userSelection=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);//KEY_DESC
         edittext=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);//KEY_EVENT
         edittext.requestFocus();
         InputMethodManager imm =(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
         if(imm != null) {
             imm.showSoftInput(edittext, 0); 
         }

         show=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
         listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.llList);

         Spinner my_spin=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        my_spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        ArrayAdapter aa=new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,items);
        aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        my_spin.setAdapter(aa);

        okButton.setOnClickListener(new clicker());
        addButton.setOnClickListener(new getclicker());

        eventsData = new classdbOpenHelper(this);

        change_date_but.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {



                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) {
                     DatePickerDialog DPD = new DatePickerDialog(
                   FirstActivity.this, mDateSetListener, mYear, mMonth,mDay);
                                DPD.show();
               }
                  });
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
              mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
              mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
              mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

              updateDisplay();
    }
     @Override
         @Deprecated

         protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       super.onPrepareDialog(id, dialog);

          ((DatePickerDialog) dialog).updateDate(mYear, mMonth, mDay);

         }

         private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

       public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {
           mYear = year;
           mMonth = monthOfYear;
       mDay = dayOfMonth;
           updateDisplay();
          }
         };

         private void updateDisplay() {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          date.setText(new StringBuilder()
            // Month is 0 based so add 1
         .append(mMonth + 1).append("-").append(mDay).append("-")
            .append(mYear));
         }







    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos, long arg3) {
        userSelection.setText(items[pos]);
    }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        userSelection.setText("");
    }



    class clicker implements Button.OnClickListener {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String datevalue = date.getText().toString();
            String Userselectvalue = userSelection.getText().toString();
            String Userevent = edittext.getText().toString();
            SQLiteDatabase  db = eventsData.getWritableDatabase();

            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(classdbOpenHelper.KEY_DESC, Userselectvalue);
            cv.put(classdbOpenHelper.KEY_EVENT, Userevent);
            cv.put(classdbOpenHelper.KEY_DATE,datevalue);
            db.insert(classdbOpenHelper.DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
            db.close();
        }




}
    class getclicker extends ListActivity implements Button.OnClickListener {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String datevalue = date.getText().toString();
            String Userselectvalue = userSelection.getText().toString();
             cursor1 = eventsData.getContact(datevalue,Userselectvalue);
             SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.events, cursor1, null, null);
                 listView = getListView();
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
        public void onDestroy() {
            eventsData.close();
          }

    }

}
```

> classdbOpenHelper.java

```
package example.showevent1;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


public class classdbOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "id";
    public static final String KEY_DESC = "countdesc";
    public static final String KEY_EVENT = "countevent";
    public static final String KEY_DATE = "countdate";

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME= "countdb";
    public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "countable";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;


    public classdbOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
       /* db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
        KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT " +
        //KEY_COUNTED + " INTEGER " +
        KEY_DESC + " TEXT NOT NULL " +
        KEY_DATE + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
                ); */
        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + "("
                + KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_DESC + " TEXT, " + KEY_EVENT + " TEXT, " + KEY_DATE + " TEXT " + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXITS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);

    }


    public Cursor getContact(String datevalue, String Userselectvalue){
        String selection = classdbOpenHelper.KEY_DESC + " = '" + Userselectvalue + "'" + " AND " + classdbOpenHelper.KEY_DATE + " = '" + datevalue+ "'";

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase(); 
        Cursor cursor = db.query(classdbOpenHelper.DATABASE_TABLE, 
             new String[] {classdbOpenHelper.KEY_EVENT }, selection, 
             null, null, null, null);
        return cursor;
    }
}
```

> activity_first.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@color/color_1"
    tools:context=".FirstActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/_add" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button2"
        android:text="Add Event" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:text="" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
        android:text="Show Event" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:textColor="#b22924" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
        android:text="@string/select"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:textColor="#b22924"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
        android:text="Select A Place" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="38dp"
        android:text="@string/dt" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

> events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <ListView
        android:id="@+id/llList"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Button01" >
    </ListView>


</LinearLayout>
```

> logcat

```
08-06 07:41:33.680: E/AndroidRuntime(3482): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-06 07:41:33.680: E/AndroidRuntime(3482): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
08-06 07:41:33.680: E/AndroidRuntime(3482):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:303)
08-06 07:41:33.680: E/AndroidRuntime(3482):     at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.init(CursorAdapter.java:174)
08-06 07:41:33.680: E/AndroidRuntime(3482):     at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.<init>(CursorAdapter.java:122)
08-06 07:41:33.680: E/AndroidRuntime(3482):     at android.support.v4.widget.ResourceCursorAdapter.<init>(ResourceCursorAdapter.java:54)
08-06 07:41:33.680: E/AndroidRuntime(3482):     at android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.<init>(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:63)
08-06 07:41:33.680: E/AndroidRuntime(3482):     at example.showevent1.FirstActivity$getclicker.onClick(FirstActivity.java:177)
08-06 07:41:33.680: E/AndroidRuntime(3482):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
08-06 07:41:33.680: E/AndroidRuntime(3482):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
08-06 07:41:33.680: E/AndroidRuntime(3482):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
08-06 07:41:33.680: E/AndroidRuntime(3482):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-06 07:41:33.680: E/AndroidRuntime(3482):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-06 07:41:33.680: E/AndroidRuntime(3482):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-06 07:41:33.680: E/AndroidRuntime(3482):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-06 07:41:33.680: E/AndroidRuntime(3482):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-06 07:41:33.680: E/AndroidRuntime(3482):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-06 07:41:33.680: E/AndroidRuntime(3482):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-06 07:41:33.680: E/AndroidRuntime(3482):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check CursorAdapter's document, It says

"The Cursor must include a column named "_id" or this class will not work."

So you need to query column KEY_ROWID AS _id to make your cursor contains "_id".